# Re-share object via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to re-share an existing item (link, photo, text wallpost..) via the Graph API? This should have the same effect as the user pressing the "share" button on an item.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is: Don't post an original item to the user's wall, but instead make the user re-share an item that I've put on the fan page of the application to his wall.